# java application is not running on jar after sorting in packages

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jar, package

I have an application that is working for over a year,

All my classes were sitting in the default_package,

Since it got bigger  (over 30 classes), I've decided to separate it to different packages.

I refactored everything, made the changes and handled all errors.

now it works perfect when I run it through eclipse, but **when I export it to a runnable jar,
 it is not working.**

I tried both export methods:
**Extract** required Libraries....
and
**Package** required Libraries

doesn't work on either...

when I run it from command prompt I get the following error:

```
 E:\Request Server 3.0>java -jar RequestSrvV3DB1111.jar

 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dudug.RequestServer.ServerInfoPanel.<init>(ServerInfoPanel.java:110)
    at dudug.RequestServer.RequestServerDB$1.run(RequestServerDB.java:56)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Please HELP !!!**

Comment: Would you please schow us the line, where the error occured? Line `110` in `ServerInfoPanel`.

Comment: how stupid of me :) I didn't know this number was reffering to a line number, you helped me solve this. in this line there was aceess to a new property that I didn't add to the txt file. now everything works perfect  ,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel silly.

@Chasmo enlightened me that the number after the class name (ServerInfoPanel.java:**110**)
was referring to the problematic line,

I checked there
and I found this code:

```
if (props.getProperty("OfflineDB").equals("0"))
         dbOfflineMode.setBackground(Color.green);
     else
         dbOfflineMode.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

I forgot to add the value "OfflineDB" to my propFile, and that was the problem.

thanks @Chasmo